# bootstrap-select not changing inside <fieldset>

Tags: html, css, material-design, bootstrap-select

I'm using this plugin [silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select), but it's not working inside the fieldset element(the UI is working well). Also, I'm using this template in my project. To be specific, **ADVANCED FORM EXAMPLE WITH VALIDATION** is what I am using as you can see in this template https://gurayyarar.github.io/AdminBSBMaterialDesign/pages/forms/form-wizard.html

When I click any options, it doesnt change

This is my code:

```
<form id="wizard_with_validation" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
     <div class="row clearfix">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <div class="form-group form-float">
                 <select class="form-control show-tick">
                      <option value="">-- Please select --</option>
                      <option value="wpk">PK Holder</option>
                      <option value="npk">Non-PK Holder</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO can you show us your code so far what you have achieved

Comment: already update my post

Comment: No i mean a working example on snippet or code-pen